# Javascript library suggestion for carpentry/glassware management: Cuts and profiles

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a library that allows me to have control of the divs' or canvas 2d according to the input that we indicate or dragging, but I did not find any. Do you suggest any library (not necessarily to do everything).

[image]

In short, according to the example image. I want to manage with Javascript to move the doors size or move them. I don't know of a bookstore that makes it easy for me to do that. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can try Syncfusion [Javascript Diagram control](https://www.syncfusion.com/javascript-ui-controls/js-diagram) https://www.syncfusion.com/javascript-ui-controls/js-diagram

- Visualize, create, and edit interactive diagrams.
- Build flowcharts, BPMN shapes, and mind maps.
- Load wide range of nodes with optimal performance.
- Auto-arrange nodes on any complex layout.
- Experience seamless interaction and editing capabilities.

The whole suite of controls is available for free (commercial applications also) through the community license program if you qualify. The community license is the full product with no limitations or watermarks.

https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense

Note: I work for Syncfusion.